# How to transfer data from view (twig file) to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view, controller

**I'm using Laravel 5.** I have a function in my Controller, which use some of my params. This params I save in my view, while the user enters them in the input. And I need this data to transfer to my controller. Is it possible? Maybe anybody has had the same problem, I hope You can help.
Thank You!

Here is my controller:

```
$databaseLogin = new DatabaseController();
  $dbRequest = $databaseLogin->loginReq($login, $passwd);
  return view('login');
```

And here is my view:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Login">
<input type="password" name="passwd" id="pass" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: do you needed to pass name and password to controller?

Comment: @dasacodec Yes, I do

Comment: create a POST route and handle a form with csrf token and `Request $request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do if from post request

1.First create a route

```
Route::POST('your route’, 'yourController@add');
```

2.Then create a form with csrf token in view

```
<form action="{{url(‘your route’)}}" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}

<input type=”text” name=”username”>
<input type=”text” name=”password”>
<input type=”submit” value=”login”>
</form>
```

3.Then you can get the values in your controller

```
Public function add(Request $request){
    $name = $request.username;
    $password= $request.password;
//code continues
}
```